# How to create roll-up summary field on Master Object to display Status of most recent line item?

Tags: master-detail, roll-up-summary

The relationship between the objects is Master-Detail. Object1 - Ticket | Object2 - Tasks.
I'd like to display Status of most recent Task (line item) record on Ticket Object. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: you can't use RSF on Task as it has a polymorphic relationship to many parents. This is where [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) comes in - the go to answer for this type of issue (Task rollups, rollups over lookup relationships)

Comment: Object2 'Tasks' is custom object (not the one under activities) and share a master-detail relationship with Object1 'Ticket'. I'd like to have a roll-up summary field or any other solution to display Status from most recent Tasks record on master object Ticket.

Comment: OK, DLRS is still the solution for your use case