# Is there a way to display most recent Status from custom child object on custom master object?

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, roll-up-summary

There are two objects and they have a master-detail relationship. Object1 'Course' | Object2 'Sessions'. Is there a way to display Session Status of most recent Session record on Course Object? and how? Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/352891 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a trigger or flow. Whenever a session is created or updated the flow or trigger checks all related Sessions, which is the most recent for each course and what the status is and then update the parent.